# PubSubPullSensor fails when trying to pull messages larger than 50KB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I have been trying to use PubSubPullSensor in Airflow to pull JSON messages and ingest into bigquery, whenever the message size exceeds beyond a threshold the sensor fails to pull the message and push via XCOM. I understand XCOM has a max size limit but how do we overcome such a situation and are there any workarounds for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There is dedicated solution in the Google Cloud Platform for scenario you have described. It's [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-streaming#cloudpubsubsubscriptiontobigquery) Pub/Sub Subscription to BigQuery template, which allows you to reads JSON-formatted messages from Pub/Sub and converts them to BigQuery elements.

As it is said in the [official documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/models/xcom.html), maximum XCom size is 48 KB. XComs let tasks exchange messages, allowing more nuanced forms of control and shared state. XComs don't seem like to be made for passing large amount of data.

If you wish to stay with Airflow solution and the current PubSubSensor’s functionality doesn’t fit your needs, you may develop your custom sensor using the [PubSub Hook](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_api/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_pubsub_hook/index.html).

Another solution is to use [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub), which can be triggered by messages published to Pub/Sub topics, together with Composer [DAG triggering solution](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/triggering-with-gcf). When a message is published to the Pub/Sub topic, the Cloud Function triggers the Composer DAG.

I hope you find the above pieces of information useful.